Can I use a MIT licensed emoji in my video? If I can, how?
I am using the Microsoft font fluentui-emoji released under this license.
Must I put the MIT license somewhere?

Yes, you can use MIT licensed emoji in your video.
Yes, you need to put the license terms in your video as well.
The easiest way is to include a credits section in the video (typically at the end), where you give credits to the people who participated in making the video. There you can also give credit to the source of the emoji and mention the license under which you use the emoji.
